# Form design with Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to design a search form in CSS using the Grid layout. My goal is to have the form look similar to this:

[image: this].

My approach was to have 4 rows:

- 1 row for the input/text label
- 1 row for the input/text field
- 1 row for the checkbox
- 1 row for the search button

and 10 fractional columns:

- input/text label would span 3 columns
- input/text field would span 10 columns
- checkbox would span 2/3 columns and the label would be on the same row spanning 3/4 column
- search button would be centered and span 7 columns

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
}

form {
  margin: 10% 2%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 30px;
  display: grid;
  /*row for search field, row for checkbox, empty row, search button row
    checkbox is 1 column, label is 4 columns, search button is 7 columns*/
  grid-template-rows: 60px 45px 45px 60px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
}

label {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 11;
}

input[type=text] {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 11;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
    <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="post">
      <label for="search_field">Search for:</label>
      <!--<br>-->
      <input required id="search_field" type="text" name="search_term" placeholder="Search for...">
      <br>
      <input id="is_date" type="checkbox" name="is_date" value="date">
      <label for="is_date">I'm searching for a date (e.g. 02/10)</label>
      <br><br>
      <!--<input type="submit" value="Search">-->
      <button>Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But somehow I receive the output below.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Shouldn't the input/text field be on the second row rather than on the first row with the label, etc..?

[image: this output.]

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS appears to be incomplete. There are no styles applied to several elements. It's not clear why your layout isn't working.

However, there are several ways to make the layout work. You've chosen the line-based placement method, so I'll stick with that in my answer.

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 60px 45px 45px 60px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

label[for="search_field"] {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

input#search_field {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 11;
}

input#is_date {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

label[for="is_date"] {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
}

button {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 3 / 9;
  background-color: royalblue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* for demo styles only */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
}

form > * {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

button {
  background-color: royalblue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font: 1.2em verdana;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <label for="search_field">Label</label>
  <input id="search_field" type="text" placeholder="Search for...">
  <input id="is_date" type="checkbox" value="date">
  <label for="is_date">Label for Checkbox</label>
  <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/op411ahs/1/)